# schedule auto backup the directories from Centos to FTP server

Tags: centos, backup, ftp

i have three Centos server i want to schedule autobackup some directories to my FTP server ,FTP is already installed in all servers,
i want to use crontab for schedule the backup but the SH files is not working ,i did the bellow configuration at ssh files

```
#!/bin/sh
ERNAME="user name of my ftp server"
PASSWORD="password of my ftp server"
SERVER="IP of my ftp server "

# local directory to pickup *.tar.gz file
FILE="/usr/log"

# remote server directory to upload backup
BACKUPDIR="/usr/backup"

# login to remote server
ftp -n -i $SERVER <<EOF
user $USERNAME $PASSWORD
cd $BACKUPDIR
mput $FILE/*.tar.gz
quit
EOF
```

but this configuration is not working.

Comment: Can you clarify what is not working

Comment: When i Run this SH file ,it is not backup my directories which i mentioned for backup

Comment: What happen if you execute commands one by one. I see you set variable ERNAME, not USERNAME

Comment: When i execute nothing is happen it not show any error ,but files is also not backuped

Comment: did you exec commands by hand? ON the same way they are in script, with variables and so on? Did you login successfully in to the server?

Comment: I just Run ,not any thing happen

Comment: the bellow error show.    (./backup.sh: line 8: /usr/jfiles/: is a directory
./backup.sh: line 12: /var/: is a directory
Failed to change directory.
local: $: No such file or directory
Bad directory components
)